# Map subset sum with negative numbers

Tags: np, reduction, subset-sum, np-complete

The subset sum problem is defined as following:

> Given a set of *positive* integers *s₁,...,sₙ*, is there a subset *A* of {1,...,*n*} such that the sum over *A* gives the *positive* integer *T*?

I know that the problem can be solved recursively even with negative values for *s₁,...,sₙ* and *T*, but I need to show explicitly that there is a mapping between the "signed" subset sum and the original one. Formally I need the reduction

```
SIGNED SUBSET SUM ≤ SUBSET SUM.
```

Thank you for your time!